# Fetch datas from mysql where column value contains two strings

Tags: php, mysql

I want to search in mysql database with columns containing some supplier names and it has values like. `Bansbach GmbH (default)` , `Bansbach Feinmechanik` and `Bansbach xyzsomething`. I need to get the result as an array where it contains results with columns containing exactly equal to `Bansbach` if not then check for both Bansbach and default. How to write a mysql query like this.

Now I've tried some thing like this.[only my where clause included here]

```
WHERE suppliername ='Bansbach'
```

I need some thing like

```
 WHERE if(suppliername !='Bansbach' then (check it contains both bansbach and default)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain regular SQL:

```
SELECT
  -- blah
FROM
  -- blah
WHERE
  suppliername = 'Bansbach'
  OR (
    suppliername LIKE '%Bansbach%'
    AND suppliername LIKE '%default%'
  )
;
```

**EDIT**

Why is this the same thing?

- the `OR` branch will only ever be taken, if the first condition fails, this replaces you `IF`
- "Containing both" is the same as "contain one AND contain the other"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. can I use NOT LIKE '%not use%'

Answer (score 0):

Below sql should do a job for you:

```
SELECT
  suppliername
FROM
  [TABLE NAME]
WHERE
  suppliername = 'Bansbach' OR (suppliername LIKE '%Bansbach%' AND suppliername LIKE '%default%')
```